# Как можно реализовать хранилище истории изменения сущностей в системе?

Tags: .net, clickhouse, apache-kafka, influxdb

Мне нужно реализовать сервис, суть которого в хранение записей о событиях которые произошли в системе. Используется .NET6.

События читаются из событийной шины Кафки и записываются в колоночную TSDB, наподобие ClickHouse, InfluxDB, TimeScaleDB (На данном этапе база для хранения еще не определена окончательно).

Так этот сервис должен периодически делать снимки данных, для быстрого восстановления целостности данных в случае выхода из строя частей системы. (Этот пункт и вызывает у меня затруднения).

Как можно реализовать подобную функциональность? Есть какие то готовые инструменты? Буду рад, если подскажете хотя бы направление, в котором нужно искать.

Comment: Создание снимков БД для восстановления - это разве не ответственность СУБД? Какая необходимость из вашего сервиса дергать эту функциональность?

Comment: В данном случае разрабатывается middleware система, на основе которой будут создаваться прикладные сервисы. И данная функциональность будет универсальной для всех возможных будущих модулей системы.